# A rectangle with length L and width W

Tags: calculus

A rectangle with length $L$ and width $W$ is cut into four smaller rectangles by two lines parallel to the sides. Find the maximum and minimum values of the sum of the squares of the areas of the smaller rectangles.

Comment: It seems that the maximum occurs when the lines coincide with the edges of the rectangle, to give $(WL)^2+0^2+0^2+0^2=(WL)^2$. But this doesn't really cut the rectangle into four smaller rectangles. So, technically. the question should ask for the supremum and infimum, not the maximum and minimum.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

From the above diagram let the areas of the smaller rectangles be $A_1=xy$, $A_2=(L-x)y$, $A_3=(L-x)(W-y)$, $A_4=x(W_y)$ for $0\le x\le L$, $0\le y\le W$
$$f(x,y)=A_1^2+A_2^2+A_3^2+A_4^2$$$$f(x,y)=[x^2+(L-x)^2][y^2+(W-y)^2]$$
Now find the maximum and minimum values of $f(x,y)$$$f_x(x,y)=[2x-2(L-x)][y^2+(W-y)^2]=0\implies x=\dfrac12L$$$$f_y(x,y)=[x^2+(L-x)^2][2y-2(W-y)]=0\implies y=\dfrac W2$$$$f_{xx}=4[y^2+(W-y)^2]$$$$f_{yy}=4[x^2+(L-x)^2]$$$$f_{xy}=(4x-2L)(4y-2W)$$$$D=16[y^2+(W-y)^2][x^2+(L-x)^2]-(4x-2L)^2(4y-2W)^2$$Thus when $x=\dfrac{1}{2}L$ and $y=\dfrac12W$, $D>0$ and $f_{xx}=2W^2>0$

Thus a minimum of $f$ occurs at $\left(\dfrac12L,\dfrac12W\right)$ and minimum value is $f\left(\dfrac12L,\dfrac12W\right)=\dfrac14L^2W^2$
Notice that there are no critical points, so the maximum will occur on the boundry.

Now along the width of rectangle let $g(y)=f(L,y)=L^2[y^2+(W-y)^2,0\le y\le W]$. Then $g^{\prime}(y)=L^2[2y-2(W-y)]=0\implies y=\dfrac12W$

Also $\left(\dfrac12\right)=\dfrac12L^2W^2$. Checking the endpoints we get $g(0)=g(W)=L^2W^2$.

Now along the length of the rectangle let us take $h(x)=f(x,0)=f(x,W)=W^2[x^2+(L-x)^2],0\le x\le L$

By symmetry $h^{\prime}(x)=0\implies x=\dfrac12L$ and $h\left(\dfrac12L\right)=\dfrac12L^2W^2$

At the endpoints we have $h(0)=h(L)=L^2W^2$ is the maximum value of $f$

This maximum value of $f$ occurs when the crossing lines in the diagram correspond to the sides of the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

So we originally have a rectangle:
$$A_0=L.W$$
when we make these two cuts they must originate from points along each of the sides. Imagining the rectangle placed on a Cartesian plane with one corner in the position $(0,0)$ we can see that a first line will originate from $(W-x,0)$ and a second line will originate from $(L-y,0)$ where $x$ and $y$ are the distances from the end of a vertices.

We will have now formed four rectanges, these have areas $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$

$A_1=(L-y)(W-x)$

$A_2=(L-y)(x)$

$A_3=y(W-x)$

$A_4=yx$

we will use $\sum A_i$ as the notation for the sum of these four, and this area must be equal to the original area, or:
$$\sum A_i=A_0$$

now:
$$\sum A_i^2=(L-y)^2(W-x)^2+(L-y)^2x^2+y^2(W-x)^2+y^2x^2$$

To find these minima and maxima we must differentiate , although we still have $x$ and $y$ with no link between them

Answer (score 0):

Let $L=2\ell$ and $W=2w$, and position the rectangle so that its center is at $(0,0)$ and its four corners are at $(\pm\ell,\pm w)$.  If the intersection of the horizontal and vertical cuts is at $(x,y)$, with $0\le|x|\le\ell$ and $0\le|y|\le w$, then the sum of the squares of the areas of the four subrectangles is

$$[(\ell-x)(w-y)]^2+[(\ell-x)(w+y)]^2+[(\ell+x)(w-y)]^2+[(\ell+x)(w+y)]^2=4(\ell^2+x^2)(w^2+y^2)$$

It's clear that $f(x,y)=4(\ell^2+x^2)(w^2+y^2)$ is *minimized* when $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and, for the given constraints, *maximized* when $(|x|,|y|)=(\ell,w)$.